# Common list of SQL exceptions with numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception

Can someone list some of the common SQL exceptions(with Numbers) we will be facing. Need to catch them in my project.

Language: C#
MS SQL server

Comment: Can you please specify the languane and rdbms?

Comment: C# and MS SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 17):

SQL Server error messages can be found here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx

Or you can query them with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033
```

The provider specific exception classes and error codes should be listed in the provider's documentation.

For example ODBC error codes are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714687.aspx

Comment: The query was so interesting!